# How to prevent truncating items at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve a problem where I have 3 items in a row and when resizing window I wanna first to truncate second item and after its at minWidth then start truncating first item. Currently all items are truncating at the same time.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
}

.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}

.btn {
  min-width: 30px
}

.label {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child label">
    <h3 class="truncate">Item label</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child btn truncate">
    Item Button
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Item Status
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e08m4Lcp/

Comment: Are you considering a js solution?

Comment: I am already using resizeObserver in there. The whole task is that there is row with 4 items and when resizing second item should wrap to new line and with further resizing the items left on first line should start truncating. This wrapping is done with JS and order attr. Do you have anything in mind how this resizing part could be done with JS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** If you need to favor 1 child shrinking over another inside a `flex` parent, you can use the `flex-shrink` CSS property. If you'd rather read a more official explanation, [here's the MDN docs for flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

**Solution** In your example, adding `flex-shrink: 9999;` to `.btn` will make that component shrink exclusively, until it hits its min-width.

**Sample**

```css
div {
  gap: 10px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 999999;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <p>Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

**Explanation**

`flex-shrink` works as a ratio of all values. So if you have 2 elements, `flex-shrink: 1` and `flex-shrink: 2` next to one another, the `2` will shrink twice as fast as the `1`.

In order to achieve your desired result, simply set an arbitrarily large value, like `flex-shrink:9999` on an item so it will shrink exclusively (until other properties like `min-width` stops it, at which point the next item(s) will start shrinking).

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it's that simple, I spent like 3 days on it, damn.